# Logstash Configuration file in Docker ELK Compose file

Tags: docker, logstash, elastic-stack

Can I put logstash configurations in Docker ELK compose file instead of using inside Docker ELK logstash configuration files.

```
root@847847f14311:/etc/logstash/conf.d# ls
02-beats-input.conf  10-syslog.conf 30-output.conf
```

I would like to know the logstash configurations file can be store in Local host machine?

Is possible to add those "02-beats-input.conf,10-syslog.conf ,30-output.conf" configs in docker compose file, so that when I start my ELK docker image, all the logstash configurations are automatically updated/injected in Docker ELK container.?

Many thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
zoram

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking, would you mind adding more information/context to the question?

Comment: I would like to know the logstash configurations file can be store in Local host machine? instead of using inside Docker ELK Container. ?
Ist possible to add those "02-beats-input.conf,10-syslog.conf ,30-output.conf" configs in docker compose file, so that when I start my ELK docker image, all the logstash configurations are automatically updated/injected in Docker ELK container.

Comment: Yes, you can mount a file from the host into a container. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @R0MANARMY, Thanks. Yes.

Comment: There is an example of how to mount a file into a container using docker-compose in [this ticket](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15793).

Comment: Was that link helpful or are you still having an issue?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it was helpful. To be honest could not have the solution I want.   How do i add/mount "02-beats-input.conf ,10-syslog.conf, 30-output.conf" file in my docker-compose.yml http://pastie.org/10967401

Comment: @R0MANARMY I added volume in my docker-compose.yml file as like here.. http://pastie.org/10967598 That means, when my docker is up, the logstash config file are reading from that my local folder? or copy those local config files into docker container logstasg/conf.d/ automatically ?

Comment: It's more helpful if you include your docker-compose file in the question rather than link to pastie.org. And yes, when you mount a file like that it will be read from your local folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to mount logstash file as volume

```
-v /logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/command-line-flags.html

I think you run with docker with the envirement variable to set the folder that it should ok.

```
-f, --path.config CONFIG_PATH
```

Load the Logstash config from a specific file or directory. If a directory is given, all files in that directory will be concatenated in lexicographical order and then parsed as a single config file. You can also specify wildcards (globs) and any matched files will be loaded in the order described above.